# New problem with sfdx scratch orgs / custom metadata objects

Tags: salesforcedx

We are having a new issue (maybe since Spring '19 release?) pushing code to a new scratch org.  Here is the situation:

1) we created a Managed Package that has been released, using sfdx the entire time.  Last packaged version was about two weeks ago.  Scratch orgs were working great, no issues with the development process.

2) since the Spring '19 release, we can not successfully push the code to a scratch Org  using sfdx force:source:push

3) the root error appears to be related to our Custom Metadata objects, like this one:

force-app/main/default/objects/AkoonuSettings__mdt/AkoonuSettings__mdt.object-meta.xml                    Cannot modify managed object: entity=CustomEntityDefinition, component=01I3C0000007nmI, state=MANAGED_RELEASED, Field: OptionsFlag OptionBit: OptionsFlagEnableLicensing Previous Value: null New Value: false

4) The Package can still be installed in new orgs, and if we convert the source code to a metadata package, it can be successfully deployed - so it appears this issue is specific to scratch orgs.

5) SFDX has been updated to the most recent version.

Has anyone else experienced such an issue? Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Jeff

Comment: Is this when you are deploying back to the packaging org? I see this error when trying to deploy a change back to the packaging org which would change a managed component.

Comment: Hi Zack - this is happening when pushing the source to a brand new scratch org using force:source:push.  I am able to successfully deploy to the existing packaging org with force:mdapi:deploy .

Comment: Hi Jeff - Did you ever find a solution or workaround for this? I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Yes - we did get this resolved with the help of Salesforce's support.  Turns out that it was failing because our project.json had an ancestorId in it (left over from experimenting with v2 packaging).  When we removed that everything worked again.